# How is a shared property exemplified by multiple entities?

Tags: properties

For instance, if there are two people who work on building a house. Individually they exemplify the properties "able to woodwork" and "able to stonework", as a whole they exemplify the property "being able to build a house", does this mean that each individual exemplifies that same property as the whole too?

Comment: Yes, two individual dogs share the same property "to be a dog".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in the title doesn't seem to be the question that the example is about. The answer to the question in the title is:

```
That's what a property is: something that can be exemplified by multiple particulars.
```

A less confusing example to go with this question would be:

```
Able exemplifies the property "being able to build a house"
Baker exemplifies the property "being able to build a house"
Therefore the property of "being able to build a house" is exemplified by two individuals.
```

However, your example seems to be directed at a different question:

```
Can a property apply to a set in virtue of other properties applying to individuals in the set?
```

For example, a bolt cannot fasten two pieces together, but it can fasten to a nut. Likewise, a nut cannot fasten two pieces together, but it can fasten to a bolt. Because of the individual properties of bolt and nut, the pair of bolt and nut together has the property that it can fasten two pieces together.

If that's your question, I think the answer is that there isn't any rule for this behavior because there are so many disparate examples in the natural world where the properties of a system are a sort of composition of the properties of the parts. On the other hand, it's not a purely empirical question either, because it is often possible to predict *a priori* what composition property a system will have based on the properties of the parts.

For example, if you have never seen a nut and bolt before. If someone showed it to you and let you experiment with how it works and how strong the connection is, you could predict that it would hold two pieces together.

So, I think the answer to the second question is: in too many ways to list.

Comment: Thank you, the nut and bolt example really helps